# I have set a secret key, but keep getting the error 'RuntimeError: A secret key is required to use CSRF.'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am quite new with Flask, having some trouble getting this running. I have set a secret key but keep getting the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
app.config['SECRET KEY'] = 'secrfgdgret'

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username')
    password = PasswordField('password')

@app.route('/')
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('register.html',)





@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html',)


@app.route('/drive')
def drive():
    return render_template('drive.html',)

@app.route('/deliver')
def deliver():
    return render_template('deliver.html',)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Add an underscore in `app.config['SECRET KEY'] = ...` so it becomes `app.config['SECRET_KEY']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas Weller suggests, add an underscore to `'SECRET KEY'`-> `'SECRET_KEY'` in `app.config['SECRET_KEY']`

Comment: In case of a simple typo, we prefer to close the question. There's even a specific close vote reason which mentions typos.